# Не работает свойство getBoundingClientRect, скажите почему?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id='aut'>AUT</p>
 <script>
   let aut = document.querySelector('#aut')
   alert(aut.getBoundingClientRect());
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Метод elem.getBoundingClientRect() возвращает координаты в контексте окна для минимального по размеру прямоугольника, который заключает в себе элемент elem, в виде объекта встроенного класса DOMRect.

Comment: А в чём ошибка?

Comment: Ознакомитесь с теорией https://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates#koordinaty-otnositelno-okna-getboundingclientrect

Comment: не работает, или работает но не так как Вы ожидаете?

Comment: всё работает : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/abvbpRJ

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вывести так:

```js
let aut = document.querySelector('#aut');
let {left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, height} = aut.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, height);
```

Все свойства описаны [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), в возвращаемых значениях

Answer (score -1):

```
let aut = document.querySelector('#aut');

function showRect(elem) {
  let r = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  alert(`x:${r.x}
y:${r.y}
width:${r.width}
height:${r.height}
top:${r.top}
bottom:${r.bottom}
left:${r.left}
right:${r.right}
`);
}
showRect(aut);
```